# azure takes a long time to create and run a container instance

Tags: azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I am running a Linux Azure Container Instance. This is for a workflow where a container is created, runs a script, and is destroyed. The equivalent of "docker run -rm" Why does azure take approximately 1 minute to spin up this container. My container runs in a few seconds, but it takes the fabric at least 50 seconds to respond. This container is 200MB at most.

Comment: to confirm, I've always has the same issue. We use Terraform to provision, so we run and wait. Some images can take upwards of 10 mins to provision and in some cases fail due to azure region resource limits. Want containers? Use AKS

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will be able to tell you why there is a difference between both cases.
but is it possible to try another azure region to maybe get another region which is less busy on the ACI side.

Azure Container instances use  a caching mechanism to speed up container startup for images built from common windows images.
This is used a lot for Linux ubuntu. So have you checked on this side ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting. Have a nice day.